# Erro de rotas no php

Tags: php, codeigniter

Comecei o desenvolvimento de um sistema utilizando o framework codeigniter 3.
No localhost não tive problemas com rotas, porém depois que coloquei o sistema no servidor começou a aparesentar problemas nas rotas para as views.

Problema:

> 404 Page Not Found

Inspecionei o código pelo navegador e na aba network, ao clicar no link que me direciona a view, apresenta o mesmo problema.

Observação: Foi alterado o arquivo `config.php`, no qual alterei a linha de do código `$config['base_url']` para pegar a url do servidor.

O php 5.6 está instalado.

Segue o arquivo `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|images|js|css|uploads|favicon.png)
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L]
```

Segue um código com os links das views:

```
 <ul class="treeview-menu">
                        <?php if($this->session->userdata("perfil") == 1): ?>
                            <li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>manutencao/categorias"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Categorias</a></li>
                            <li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>manutencao/clientes"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Clientes</a></li>
                            <li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>manutencao/produtos"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Produtos</a></li>
                            <li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>manutencao/responsaveis"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Responsáveis</a></li>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>manutencao/ordens"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Ordens de Serviço</a></li>
                    </ul>
```

Obrigado.

Comment: E a estrutura do CI, você tem usado com o nome Maiusculo para o nome dos arquivos de controllers e models?

Comment: isso, usei desse jeito, tem algum problema?

Comment: mudei tudo para minusculo os nomes dos arquivos e agora não acha nenhuma view

Comment: voltei o que tava antes, na verdade o problema era o nome de uma pasta que estava Maiusculo e coloquei minusculo e funcionou. Os controllers deixei maiusculo (primeira letra)